# MousePressed gets wrong source JPanel

Tags: mouseevent, jlabel

Im coding a simple movegame and i have some troubles with the MouseListener.

**This is the View of the game**

[image: This is the View of the game]

the single panels are defined in an Array and each of them has a mouse listener

```
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {

        labels[i] = new JLabel();
        labels[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));

        if (numbers[i] != null) {
            labels[i].addMouseListener(mausListener);
            labels[i].setBorder(border);
            labels[i].setText(Integer.toString(numbers[i]));
            labels[i].setFont(font);
            labels[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            labels[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            labels[i].setOpaque(true);
        } else {
            labels[i].setText("null");
            labels[i].setVisible(false);
        }

        this.add(labels[i]);

    }
```

numbers is an Array filled with the unsorted numbers:

```
[8, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 7, null, 6]
```

This is my mouseListener:

```
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    clicked = (JLabel) e.getSource();

    if (clicked.getText() != "null") {

        System.out.println(clicked.getText());
        logik.move(Integer.parseInt(clicked.getText()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(logik.getNummern()));
    }
}
```

The move function checks if the clicked label is a possible label and switches it with the null-label. This function was given by our professor so there will be no mistake in it.
Now the Problem is when I click the null-label after I clicked, for example, the "6" label, the mousePressed function give me the "6" label as source Object although I pressed the null-label.

I hope someone can help me out of this.

Thank you all :D

Comment: Okay never mind I found the answer. I forgot to remove the old labels from the grid, before i added the new ones. I know, it's a dump mistake